# C++ vector of strings segfault

Tags: c++, string, vector, c++14

can anyone tell me why this segfaults?

```
vector<string> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; /* 1 million */ i++) {
    vec.push_back("string"+i);
}
```

Compiled in `g++` with `-std=c++14`

Comment: What do you think `"string"+i` actually does?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ concatenates

Comment: It doesn't. It applies weird pointer arithmetics. You're accessing addresses that are out of range, and you're not having rights to access.

Comment: @iPherian C++ is not like those other languages you know. You should probably start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: `"string"` is not actually a `string` (meaning an instance of the `std::string` class), by the way; it's an *array of `const char*`*.

Comment: @KyleStrand: a `const` array of `char` then.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe ...right, didn't mean to say it was an array of pointers. Oops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As panta-rei correctly pointed out, it looks like you're trying to contain a string of the form

```
"string" + string form of (i)
```

but you're actually doing pointer arithmetic which is illogical in this case (you're just passing a pointer incremented `i` from some location - who knows what's in that memory?).

In order to do what you want, you can use [`std::to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/), which will translate `i` to a proper C++ string. The addition of a C-style string with that, [is OK](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B).

Change your line to

```
vec.push_back("string"+to_string(i));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<string> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    vec.push_back("string" + to_string(i));
}
```

this is not PHP...